# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n!)^2}{n^{3n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Is the series  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n!)^2}{n^{3n}}$  convergent?

I tried using the Ratio Test, however, when I simplified there was still a factorial. Any ideas on another way?

Comment: The root test might be more useful (knowking Stirling's approximation)

Comment: "when I simplified there was still a factorial". How??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the ratio test does work.

$$a_n=\frac{n!^2}{n^{3n}}$$
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)!^2}{(n+1)^{3n+3}}$$

So $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)!^2}{(n+1)^{3n+3}}*\frac{n^{3n}}{n!^2}$$
$$=(n+1)^{-1}*(\frac{n}{n+1})^{3n}$$

Which, when taken the limit to infinity gets:

$$0*\text{finite number}=0$$

Comment: Maybe some in-between steps might be useful for the op: $\frac{((n + 1)!)^2}{(n!)^2} = \left(\frac{(n + 1)!}{n!}\right)^2 = (n+1)^2$. For the second factor one obtains $$\frac{n^{3n}}{(n + 1)^{3n + 3}} = \frac{n^{3n}}{(n + 1)^{3n} (n + 1)^3} = \left(\frac{n}{n + 1}\right)^{3n} \frac{1}{(n + 1)^3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using AM-GM,
$$\frac{1 + 2 + \cdots + n}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots n} = \sqrt[n]{n!}$$
so we arrive at
$$n! \le \left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)^n$$
This means that
$$\frac{(n!)^2}{n^{3n}} \le \frac{(n+1)^{2n}}{n^{2n} \cdot 2^{2n}n^n} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n} \cdot\frac{1}{2^{2n}n^n} < \frac{e^2}{2^{2n}n^n} < \frac{e^2}{2^{2n}}$$
and this last value is just a geometric series, which will clearly converge.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

By ratio test we obtain

$$\frac{((n+1)!)^2}{(n+1)^{3n+3}}\frac{n^{3n}}{(n!)^2}=\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{3n}}$$